# C# program sending email, always marked "Suspected Spam" by Gmail

Tags: email, spam-prevention, c#

I wrote a simple email program for a client.
It sends an email.  Just one.  No bulk operation here.
Yet, every email is marked as "Suspected Spam" by Gmail.

I read that there is a statistical word-use analysis in spam filtering.
So, I removed the links, the html, the mention of a "survey" to do, and everything commercial-sounding.  I made the email with JUST the subject "Dinner Tonight?" and the plain text message "Feel like Japanese tonight? Call me, yo"

There's nothing left content-wise to flag this as spam.  I tried a few other messages, like "Can I borrow your math textbook" and other boring content with boring subjects.

Every single one is flagged as spam.
The headers say "X-CGO-SPAM: SUSPECT".  This message has not helped me hunt down the issue.  Most of the false positive spam troubleshooting just has to do with changing the language you use, with a few other rules, but I'm not violating one that I can find.

What on earth is the problem?  Is it in my C# code itself?  I'd post this on stackoverflow, but I think it's more of a networking/OS thing.

I'm using the AegisImplicitMail library, because it is suitable for port 465.
The code is very basic.  In fact, it may just be the example in the documentation with no real alteration (see below).

```
var mymessage = new MimeMailMessage();
mymessage.From = new MimeMailAddress(mailFrom);
mymessage.To.Add(mailTo);
mymessage.Subject = Properties.Settings.Default.subject;
mymessage.Body = createEmailMessage();


var mailer = new MimeMailer(host, port);
mailer.User = user;
mailer.Password = password;
mailer.SslType = SslMode.Ssl;
mailer.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationType.Base64;

mailer.SendCompleted += compEvent;
mailer.SendMailAsync(mymessage);
```

**And, below, the full raw email example, real addresses replaced with 'theSender' and 'theReceiver':**

```
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Delivered-To: theReceiver@gmail.com
Received: by 10.103.91.156 with SMTP id w28csp351188vsg;
        Sat, 3 Oct 2015 14:28:19 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.50.107.104 with SMTP id hb8mr3311413igb.1.1443907699654;
        Sat, 03 Oct 2015 14:28:19 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <theSender@cogeco.ca>
Received: from fvipsab01.cogeco.net (smtp4.cogeco.ca. [216.221.81.70])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id c192si13303309ioe.50.2015.10.03.14.28.19
        for <theReceiver@gmail.com>;
        Sat, 03 Oct 2015 14:28:19 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of theSender@cogeco.ca designates 216.221.81.70 as permitted sender) client-ip=216.221.81.70;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of theSender@cogeco.ca designates 216.221.81.70 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=theSender@cogeco.ca
Message-Id: <f9431e$h4onk@fvipsab01.cogeco.net>
X-SBRS: -4.0
X-Cloudmark-SP-Filtered: true
X-Cloudmark-SP-Result: v=1.1 cv=g7HXliF+3TU1X7xp1wYHXadBN8bSSg5nnwoLLlduasI= c=1 sm=2
 a=26eXghwQi62-kgqSx3kA:9 a=wPNLvfGTeEIA:10
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: A2Bp5QBQRxBWPO+R6xheGQGCUAozAoEahwCGI7ENAQGBZIYUBAIlgQU+DwEBAQEBAQEGAQEBAUE/QQEBAgGDfj1BAQIuGTIKiFsFpQCHXY5rnl8bgmCBNQWVfHioAjkBAQGBcQEBAQcBAQEBgmiCUix4XIRwg3kBAgM
X-IPAS-Result: A2Bp5QBQRxBWPO+R6xheGQGCUAozAoEahwCGI7ENAQGBZIYUBAIlgQU+DwEBAQEBAQEGAQEBAUE/QQEBAgGDfj1BAQIuGTIKiFsFpQCHXY5rnl8bgmCBNQWVfHioAjkBAQGBcQEBAQcBAQEBgmiCUix4XIRwg3kBAgM
Subject: [SUSPECTED SPAM] Total cool man
X-CGO-SPAM: SUSPECT
X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="5.17,630,1437451200"; 
   d="scan'208";a="17982196"
X-SMTPAUTH: True
Received: from d24-235-145-239.home1.cgocable.net (HELO smtp.cogeco.ca) ([24.235.145.239])
  by fvipsab01.cogeco.net with ESMTP; 03 Oct 2015 17:28:20 -0400
X-Mailer: AIM.MimeMailer
DATE: Saturday, October 3, 2015
FROM: theSender@cogeco.ca
TO: theReceiver@gmail.com
REPLY-TO: theSender@cogeco.ca
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="#SEPERATOR2#"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

--#SEPERATOR2#
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

You feel like dinner tonight, with mom?

--#SEPERATOR2#--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spam detection is based [on a variety of criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques) and it's up to each e-mail server to decide which checks they perform and the relevance of each check.

I think given the presence of "CGO" indicating it as "SUSPECT" and you using cogeco.ca as your mail server, it would appear that it's actually Cogeco that are suspicious of your e-mail being Spam and Google perhaps is parsing that header or the Cogeco amended signature including "SUSPECTED SPAM" in the subject and using it as a flag to place it in the spam folder?

It could be something like the "X-Mailer: AIM.MimeMailer" which gives away you're not a typical user using Outlook etc. or it could be that your messages aren't long enough to look like real messages.

I would ring Cogeco and ask them why your e-mail is falling fowl of their spam checks.

Comment: It never occurred to me that this was cogecos issue, or that the program of origin should matter.  After some research, I've become convinced that you are right.  It just seems like a bad scenario, since any program one might write won't have as much freedom as an already established email program.  But I guess there's no reason to whine about the way things ought to be.  Email is a dark and terrible thing.

Comment: "since any program one might write won't have as much freedom as an already established email program".. this is easy to fake :-) I note you are using the Aegis Implicit Mail library; see if you can remove the AIM.MimeMailer reference using that library, or just use the standard .NET way of e-mailing like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66257/Sending-Mails-in-NET-Framework.aspx ..of course it could be something else triggering it though.